# Expanding command with optional arguments: \edef

Tags: macros, expansion, optional-arguments

I have defined a LaTeX command with an optional argument, e.g., `\newcommand*{\commA}[1][opt]{A#1}`, and I cannot get it to be part of an expanded command defintion with `\edef`, e.g., `\edef\expcom{\commA}`.

I have tried different combinations to find out what is going on: first, if I define the command `\commA` without optional arguments, the code compiles smoothly. Second, if I leave `\commA` definition with optional arguments, but I define `\expcom` with `\def`, the code compiles smoothly, too. Thus, It is only the combination of **optional argument** definition and **`\edef`** that it is faulty.

How can I pass a command with optional arguments to a `\edef` definition?

See example of buggy code

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

%\newcommand*{\commA}{A} %This definition gives no error
\newcommand*{\commA}[1][opt]{A#1} %This definition raises error "! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }."

\edef\expcomm{\commA}
%\def\expcomm{\commA} %The definition with \def gives no error
\def\noexpcomm{\commA}

\noindent
This is \verb|\expcomm|: \expcomm\\
This is \verb|\noexpcomm|; \noexpcomm\\

\renewcommand*{\commA}{B}

\noindent
This is \verb|\expcomm|: \expcomm\\
This is \verb|\noexpcomm|; \noexpcomm\\

\end{document}
```

The output I would expect with the `\commA` definition with optional argument is following:
[image]

When I use the `\commA` definition without optional argument I get following, as expected:

[image]

Comment: Commands with an optional argument don't survive `\edef`. Please, tell us what you really want to achieve, unless this is just an academic question.

Comment: you can't such a \newcommand is not expandable.

Comment: ...and if you try `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\commA{O{opt}}{A#1}` the new kernel will happily inform you that `LaTeX cmd Error: Argument specification 'O{opt}' for expandable command '\commA' ends with optional argument.` ... so I suppose it can't be done.

Comment: @egreg, (at)ulrike, (at)Rmano. Okay, thanks for ultra quick answer. Leave it like that. The certain knowledge that I cannot expand a command with optional arguments is already an achievement for me (sigh). I am in amidst of a complicated code and I cannot summarize in two words what I am trying to achive, but If I get to, I'll surely ask.

Comment: You can expand a command with optional argument(s) _if_ the last argument is not optional...

Comment: @PaulGaborit It sounds good, would you give me a simple example. I have tried to change the definition `\newcommand{\commA}[2][opt]{A#1} ` so that the last argument is not optional, but `\edef\expcomm{\commA[1]{}}` still throws error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an expandable command with optional arguments provided

1. the optional arguments are followed by a mandatory one;
2. you use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`. (For [LaTeX release before 2020-10-01](http://file:///tmp/mozilla_jpa0/tb129ltnews32.pdf) include the `xparse` package)

So with

```
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\commA}{O{opt}m}{A#1}
```

you can call

```
\edef\expcommA{\commA{}}
\edef\expcommB{\commA[new]{}}
```

Note the dummy mandatory argument.

Full test document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\commA}{O{opt}m}{A#1}

\begin{document}

\edef\expcommA{\commA{}}
\edef\expcommB{\commA[new]{}}

\texttt{\meaning\expcommA}

\texttt{\meaning\expcommB}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I believe this is a typical [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), though.

Comment: It was, doubtless, an XY problem; in the meanwhile I found an alternative fix (not really clean) without having to expand the macro with optional argument, however, this was the first possible solution I came across ´:). I am sure, someone else is gonna benefit from this contribution.

Answer (score 0):

In case it doesn't matter if `\commA` is not replaced by its replacement-text during the `\edef` you can use `\protected@edef` for having expanding `\commA` suppressed while having the tokens forming its optional argument expanded if provided.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\commA}[1][opt]{A#1} %This definition raises error "! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }."

\csname protected@edef\endcsname\expcomm{\commA}

\noindent This is \verb|\expcomm|: \texttt{\meaning\expcomm}

\newcommand\foobar{expansion of \string\foobar}
\csname protected@edef\endcsname\expcommOptionalArgExpanded{\commA[\foobar]}

\noindent This is \verb|\expcommOptionalArgExpanded|: \texttt{\meaning\expcommOptionalArgExpanded}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But in your case it seems to matter as in your question you have `\commA` redefined somewhere in the middle of your example...